how to convert nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) to xml in sql server
I am trying to convert msdb jobs messages to xml.
I am using Ola Hallengren backup routines.
when I run the following routine it works amazing and converts everything.
now, if I change the number 3333 to 3702 it fails.
I cannot identify what is after the character 3701 in the message, but that is holding me back to convert the full message to xml
If you use Ola's you can test on your own system. let me know if you find out how to change my function so that I can successfully convert nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) to xml.
create or alter  FUNCTION dbo.fnCleanString (@InputString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CleanedString VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @Char VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @Index INT = 1;
    DECLARE @Len INT = 3333-- LEN(@InputString);

    WHILE @Index <= @Len
    BEGIN
        SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1);
        IF (ASCII(@Char) NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 31 OR ASCII(@Char) IN (9, 10, 13))
        BEGIN
            SET @CleanedString += @Char;
        END
        SET @Index += 1;
    END

    RETURN @CleanedString;
END
go

SELECT TOP 50
    SysJobs.name,
    SysJobs.enabled,
    Job.message AS Message_Text,
    TRY_CAST(
        (SELECT dbo.fnCleanString(Job.message) AS [text()]
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS XML
    ) AS Message_XML
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory Job WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs SysJobs WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON Job.job_id = SysJobs.job_id
WHERE SysJobs.name = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL'
ORDER BY Job.instance_id DESC;


I got a function that has been working well for me in all tests I did.
mostly I have queried tables and views from the msdb database.
here it is the function:
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SplitStringXML') IS NULL
  EXEC ('
  
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringXML
(
  @TXT VARCHAR(1008)
 )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1008)
    AS
    BEGIN
       RETURN  (select [radhe] = ''Hare Krishna - foo bar'' );  
    END
  
  ')
GO
--DROP FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringXML  

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringXML(@List NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS XML
WITH SCHEMABINDING, ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT TRY_CAST(
            (
                SELECT 
                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                        SUBSTRING(@List, n, 1), 
                        '&', '&amp;'), 
                        '<', '&lt;'), 
                        '>', '&gt;'), 
                        '''', '&apos;'), 
                        '"', '&quot;')
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n
                    FROM 
                        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS D1(n),
                        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS D2(n),
                        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS D3(n),
                        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS D4(n)
                ) AS Numbers
                WHERE n <= LEN(@List)
                  AND (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@List, n, 1)) NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 31
                       OR ASCII(SUBSTRING(@List, n, 1)) IN (9, 10, 13))
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ) AS XML
    )
END
GO

this is an example as how I have been using this function:
   -----  the way this function has been used:

            SELECT TOP 5000
                SysJobs.name,
                SysJobs.enabled,
                Job.message AS Message_Text,
                Message_XML = dbo.SplitStringXML(Job.message)
            FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory Job WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs SysJobs WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON Job.job_id = SysJobs.job_id
            --WHERE SysJobs.name = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL'
            ORDER BY Job.instance_id DESC;

challenge:
If you find any situation where converting a nvarchar(max) to xml is causing you problems when using this function, let me know.

The numbers 3701 and 3702 vary depending on where in the Job history [message] a left chevron bracket is encountered. The conversion fails on IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1) which forms part of the code for creating folders using [xp_create_subdir] in module [DatabaseBackup].
I don't confess to being an XML or encoding expert, but a dirty/simple way of working around this specific issue would be to replace <> with != in the @InputString (at the top of your function before setting @Len to LEN(@InputString)). You could create a pull request to change the code globally in Ola's maintenance solution - but I don't recommend it as it would be a philosophical war akin to tabs versus spaces (as well as being a lot of hassle/risk).
A more extensible way of fixing your function would be to replace SET @CleanedString += @Char; with SET @CleanedString += CASE @Char WHEN '<' THEN '&lt;' ELSE @Char END; within your function to specifically handle left chevron brackets. This will change the output to IF @ReturnCode &lt;&gt; 0 RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1) in the returned XML.
The CASE statement can be extended to deal with additional control characters which might find their way into the Job history [message]. There are lists and approaches for handling all control characters in XML (for example the first Link you provided, which makes my head hurt).

+1, wonderful, you pointed me out to the missing link, I will try to implement something and come back to this.
